# What are the inverse function and inverse Jacobian of $f(x,y,z) = \left(\frac{ix^2 + hy^2}{2}, \frac{jy^2+kz^2}{2}, \frac{mx^2 + nz^2}{2} \right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> What are the inverse function and inverse Jacobian of $f(x,y,z) = \left(\frac{ix^2 + hy^2}{2}, \frac{jy^2+kz^2}{2}, \frac{mx^2 + nz^2}{2} \right)$?

Assuming we are at a point $(x,y,z)$ such that $f'(x,y,z)$ is invertible, there exists an inverse function $f^{-1}(a,b,c)=(x,y,z)$ by the inverse function theorem. In trying to find this function explicitly, my solution becomes increasingly messy, such that I have, for example:

$$ x = \sqrt{\frac{2ajn-2bhn+2hck}{ijn+hn}}.$$

If I'm going to solve for the Jacobian of this inverse eventually, it would be extremely tedious to have to deal with $x$ in the form above. Is there a better way? I'm simply using substitution to solve for $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Do you know that a closed form for the inverse exists?

Comment: For an invertible matrix? Yes. Or are you saying there's a closed for for the inverse of the function? I think it's finding an explicit form for the inverse of the function that is my real problem.

Comment: May I delete the old inverses? Thank's.

Comment: sure thats fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some answers:

$$\begin{gathered}
  f(x,y,z) = (\frac{{i{x^2} + h{y^2}}}{2},\frac{{j{y^2} + k{z^2}}}{2},\frac{{m{x^2} + n{z^2}}}{2}) \hfill \\
  Df(x,y,z) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {ix}&0&{mx} \\ 
  {hy}&{jy}&0 \\ 
  0&{kz}&{nz} 
\end{array}} \right) \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
  Det(Df(x,y,z)) = (hkm + ijn)xyz \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
  Det(Df(x,y,z)) \ne 0 \Leftrightarrow hkm + ijn \ne 0 \wedge xyz \ne 0 \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
  \Delta  = Det(Df(x,y,z)) = (hkm + ijn)xyz \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
  {\left( {Df} \right)^{ - 1}}(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{\Delta }\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {jnyz}&{kmxz}&{ - jmxy} \\ 
  { - hnyz}&{inxz}&{hmxy} \\ 
  {hkyz}&{ - ikxz}&{ijxy} 
\end{array}} \right) \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
  Df(x,y,z) \cdot {\left( {Df} \right)^{ - 1}}(x,y,z) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  1&0&0 \\ 
  0&1&0 \\ 
  0&0&1 
\end{array}} \right) \hfill \\
    \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

To calculate inverse, observe first: With
$$M = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  i&h&0 \\ 
  0&j&k \\ 
  m&0&n 
\end{array}} \right)$$
we have
$$f(x,y,z) = M \cdot \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{x^2}} \\ 
  {{y^2}} \\ 
  {{z^2}} 
\end{array}} \right)$$
Setting
$$M \cdot \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{x^2}} \\ 
  {{y^2}} \\ 
  {{z^2}} 
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  u \\ 
  v \\ 
  w 
\end{array}} \right)$$
$$\Delta  = \det (M) = {\text{h k m  +  i j n}}$$
we get:
$${M^{ - 1}} = \frac{2}{\Delta }\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {jn}&{ - hn}&{hk} \\ 
  {km}&{in}&{ - ik} \\ 
  { - jm}&{hm}&{ij} 
\end{array}} \right)$$
and
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{x^2}} \\ 
  {{y^2}} \\ 
  {{z^2}} 
\end{array}} \right) = {M^{ - 1}}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  u \\ 
  v \\ 
  w 
\end{array}} \right)$$

Now begin to control the signs by solving the quadratics. Because
$$\begin{gathered}
   + x \Rightarrow  + y, - y, + z, - z \hfill \\
   - x \Rightarrow  + y, - y, + z, - z \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$
there are eight posibillities. 
We set
$$\vec U = {(u,v,w)^T}$$
and for the rows from ${M^{ - 1}}$ we write:
$$\begin{gathered}
  a = (jn, - hn,hk) \hfill \\
  b = (km,in, - ik) \hfill \\
  c = ( - jm,hm,ij) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
then we have in a more compact way:
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{x^2}} \\ 
  {{y^2}} \\ 
  {{z^2}} 
\end{array}} \right) = {M^{ - 1}}\vec U = \frac{2}{\Delta }\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {a \cdot \vec U} \\ 
  {b \cdot \vec U} \\ 
  {c \cdot \vec U} 
\end{array}} \right)$$
This leads us now to:
$$\begin{gathered}
  g(\vec U) = \sqrt {\frac{2}{\Delta }} \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\sqrt {a \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  {\sqrt {b \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  {\sqrt {c \cdot \vec U} } 
\end{array}} \right),g(\vec U) = \sqrt {\frac{2}{\Delta }} \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\sqrt {a \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  {\sqrt {b \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  { - \sqrt {c \cdot \vec U} } 
\end{array}} \right) \hfill \\
  g(\vec U) = \sqrt {\frac{2}{\Delta }} \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\sqrt {a \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  { - \sqrt {b \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  {\sqrt {c \cdot \vec U} } 
\end{array}} \right),g(\vec U) = \sqrt {\frac{2}{\Delta }} \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\sqrt {a \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  { - \sqrt {b \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  { - \sqrt {c \cdot \vec U} } 
\end{array}} \right) \hfill \\
  g(\vec U) = \sqrt {\frac{2}{\Delta }} \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - \sqrt {a \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  {\sqrt {b \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  {\sqrt {c \cdot \vec U} } 
\end{array}} \right),g(\vec U) = \sqrt {\frac{2}{\Delta }} \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - \sqrt {a \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  {\sqrt {b \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  { - \sqrt {c \cdot \vec U} } 
\end{array}} \right) \hfill \\
  g(\vec U) = \sqrt {\frac{2}{\Delta }} \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - \sqrt {a \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  { - \sqrt {b \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  {\sqrt {c \cdot \vec U} } 
\end{array}} \right),g(\vec U) = \sqrt {\frac{2}{\Delta }} \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - \sqrt {a \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  { - \sqrt {b \cdot \vec U} } \\ 
  { - \sqrt {c \cdot \vec U} } 
\end{array}} \right) \hfill \\
   \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

Comment: Thanks. I will digest this but from what I can see, your approach is to find the inverse Jacobian first because it seems easier. So, there are six different values for $g$ -- I assume this is because of the squares of $x,y,z$ in $f$. What method did you use to find $g$? Substitution?

Comment: @mathjacks Yes. Quadratics in this case have two signs. Inverting the Jacobian first is indeed easier. Only linear operations.
Ahhm helpers? The truth? Mathematica. I know the rules to do it by myself,
but in this case, (controlling the signs) costs a lot of time and concentration too. So I gave Wolfram the job.
To calculate the inverse: One way, solve the system
$$\begin{gathered}
  \frac{{i{x^2} + h{y^2}}}{2} = u \hfill \\
  \frac{{j{y^2} + k{z^2}}}{2} = v \hfill \\
  \frac{{m{x^2} + n{z^2}}}{2} = w \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$
for $x$,$y$ and $z$. That's the way to go.

Comment: Question about your solution: Say I want to make restrictions on (x,y,z) such that $f(x,y,z)$ is injective and surjective throughout its entire domain (not just locally). Is it enough to restrict each of $x,y,z$ to either it's positive or negative part such that there are 8 possible domains where $f$ is injective and surjective throughout?

Comment: Yes I think so. It's like the case $y = {x^2}$, were two possible inverses exist and $x = \sqrt y $ aka $y = \sqrt x $ is taken.